# Local debugging of subdomains with VS 2015

Tags: subdomain, visual-studio-2015, iis-express, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a multi-tenant website that has to take care of any incoming request and determine the appropriate routing by the URL subdomain.

I set up the subdomain routing using [this](https://gist.github.com/maartenba/77ca6f9cfef50efa96ec) or a similar solution.

However I'm trying to access my website on my local machine using subdomains an alias website. I'm unable to get my local IIS to port to my website with the subdomain I've specified.
I want to dedicate a virtual domain name in my local machine that will port to the website I'm debugging on VS (`localhost:23456`).

I've read some answers of identical questions (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047058/get-visual-studios-to-use-subdomain) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5186680/75500) one), but it looks like the system has changed with the new IIS and Visual Studio 2015 and ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 (vNext) project configuration.

Here's what I've tried according to the answers linked above:

- I tried setting the `hosts` file porting `www.myexample.com` to `127.0.0.1` but I get a "Bad request" error when navigating to `www.myexample.com:23456` in my browser, and anyway the debugger doesn't report a request.
- I tried setting `<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":23456:www.myexample.com" />` in the *applicationhost.config* file, gets IIS to raise an error saying "Replace *hostname* with *localhost*. Any other `bindingInformation` not specificying `localhost` as the website raises that IIS error.

#### Update

After [opiants answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32061318/75500)

I knew about the *.vs* folder and that's were I was configuring the bindings indeed.
However, looks like it was the permission that caused IIS to throw errors.
Running that `netsh` command solved the issue. And BTW, since I'm only running it my own machine, I'm not gonna need to open the firewall.

**Anyway** my question is if there is a way to add a wildcard instead of each subdomain separately? Since each tenant gets a unique subdomain, the whole process of adding subdomains is going to be dynamic by nature. I need to allow an asterisk in all the 3 places:

- hosts file
- applicationhost.config file
- netsh command

It looks like I can add the asterisk in those places but it doesn't actually work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using IIS express locally?

If so, in your solution directory, there is a `.vs` folder. You need to add the binding in the `\config\applicationhost.config` file inside that folder. Then make sure that you've allowed IIS express to listen to that subdomain.

You can refer to Scott's [article on how to configure IIS Express](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx). Specifically look for this paragraph "*1. GETTING IIS EXPRESS TO SERVE EXTERNALLY OVER PORT 80*"

To be more specific, you need to run these commands:

`netsh http add urlacl url=http://{your-domain}:{custom-port}/ user=everyone`

`netsh firewall add portopening TCP {custom-port} IISExpressWeb enable ALL`

Comment: Thanks. It's working now. Looks like it's the `netsh` command I had to run.  But I want to use an asterisk instead of manually adding all subdomains in all places. Please see the update on my question.

Comment: You can add a wildcard mapping. 

`<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:23456:*" />`

`netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:23456/ user=everyone`

As you might've already guessed, this will match _every_ domain name and without registering the domain to a dns server, you'll have to create a mapping in the hosts file for each subdomain.

Comment: I tried adding a wildcard for the subdomain only and I couldn't get it to work. Have I missed something?

Comment: Do you mean like `*.something.com`? I'm afraid IIS Express does not support that.

Comment: I guess I'll have to make an external process that sets up the three stages manually upon each addition/removal of a tenant. Do you think about a better option? Is this even possible in .NET Core / DNX?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish there but I suppose you can make it dynamic by creating a handler that will match the subdomain against a tenant?

Comment: Yeah, but I need my computer to navigate `*.myexample.com` to my debugger... I think the `netsh` command treats `*` separately as if it would have been a subdomain, meaning it's not treated as an asterisk.

Comment: Thank you very much. You solved my problem with subdomain. I can confirm for asp.net 5 (vNext) - IIS Express following: 1. Edit hosts file, 2. edit \config\applicationhost.config and 3. netsh http add urlacl url=http://{your-domain}:{custom-port}/ user=everyone

netsh firewall add portopening TCP {custom-port} IISExpressWeb enable ALL

Comment: @Miroslav Thanks, Point 1: Edit Hosts file is required, should possibly be re-iterated in the answer...