# Can I use subdomain with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0, iis-express

I am trying to render my asp.net core app locally on https://localhost:44301 and also https://sub.localhost.test.

I added the following to my `hosts` file `127.0.0.1 sub.localhost.test`. Then I edited the binding info in the `C:/ProjectName/.vs/config/applicationhost.config` file to the following

```
<site name="ProjectName" id="2">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
      <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\ProjectName" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
      <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44301:localhost" />
      <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="sub.localhost.test" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```

I also trird `<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44301:sub.localhost.test" />`. But, when I go to `https://sub.localhost.test` I get `Unable To Connect` error.

Is it possible to run my local project on both `https://localhost:44301 and`https://sub.localhost.test`? If so, how?

Comment: Spend some time on what is site binding, and then the answer should be clear https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Comment: @LexLi, I installed JexusManager and added the binding directly from there to ensure  I am not missing anything, but it still does not render. When I view the "IIS Express" that is running, I don't even see the subdomain listed as a valid website. I only see a link to the https and the https links with localhost.

Comment: Run the actual diagnostics from Jexus Manager and check what the report says.

Comment: @LexLi after clearing my browser data, I am getting an error now. the error I get is ` HTTP Error 502.5 - ANCM Out-Of-Process Startup Failure ` not that the localhost:44301 is running with no error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Visual Studios to use subdomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047058/get-visual-studios-to-use-subdomain)

Answer (score 0):

Use port in the bindings. For http port 80 for https post 443

```
<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:sub.localhost.test" />
    </bindings>
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/bindings/)